# Issues configuring JBoss EAP on Netbeans 8

Tags: java, netbeans, jboss, wildfly

I have downloaded JBoss EAP 7 and am configuring it on Netbeans 8. I have reached the wizard "instance Properties" where am asked to select a "domain" from a select box. When I open the select box, it is empty. There is nothing there to choose from. Because of this, the "finish" button also is inactive which make in impossible to complete the configuration.

I am adding Jboss via the "services" tab. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 8):

JBoss EAP 6.4.0 works perfectly fine with Netbeans 8.1, however, if you are like me and wanted to take advantage of the JSF 2.2 functionality, which was only added in JBoss EAP 7.0.0, you will currently need to do some work-arounds.

In Netbeans 8.1 I managed to work around the problem with the blank domain by setting up JBoss EAP 7.0.0 selecting the "WildFly Application Server" option instead of "JBoss Application Server". Here's are more detailed instructions:

In Netbeans 8.0.1, select "Services", right click on "Servers" and select "Add Server...", pick the option "WildFly Application Server", point "server location" to the root of your JBoss EAP 7 install (e.g. c:\jboss7) and then point the server configuration option to c:\jboss7\standalone\configuration\standalone-full.xml and that's it.

However, even after doing this the application server is now added, there is still a bug where your code will not deploy correctly, see details here:

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=258091

Thankfully, this has been fixed in the Netbeans nightly build. It looks like the bug was actually fixed in Feb 2016. I installed NetBeans IDE Build 201607140002, which includes this fix (as will any other newer I presume). So, you can grab the nightly build from here (alternatively, you can wait for the bug fix in Netbeans 8.2, whenever that will be):

http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/nightly/

It should be noted, even after using the nightly build, I still had to add the server to Netbeans using the above technique (add it as a "WildFly Application Server", not a "JBoss Application Server" otherwise you will still get the blank domain issue).

Everything appears to be working as expected so far anyway using the above...  of course, there is an element of risk using the nightly build, as it's technically still in a test phase. This is the price we pay for living on the sharp edge of the sword! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for domain mode in NetBeans. What use case should be covered with a domain deployment ? We're talking about an IDE used for development.
Also I'm not sure EAP 7 is correctly detected.