# "Java EE 7" and JBoss EAP 7.0 in Netbeans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, jboss, netbeans-8

I tried to add jboss-eap-7.0 to Netbeans 8.2 according to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455757/issues-configuring-jboss-eap-on-netbeans-8).
Then, I created an enterprise application in Netbeans and set the server to JBoss. But there is not Java EE 7 option to choose. How can I have "Java EE 7" coupled with "JBoss EAP 7.0" in Netbeans 8.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are attempting is not possible for several reasons.

- While JBoss EAP 7 is EE 7 certified, it is not supported by NetBeans 8.2 / Java 8, and cannot be installed successfully.
- If you followed the workaround in the link you cited, you told NetBeans that you were installing WildFly when you were actually installing JBoss. That may have allowed the installation to proceed, but it is not surprising that you had problems creating an app for that server afterwards.
- Also, JBoss EAP 7 will not work with Java 8. See [this link](https://developer.jboss.org/message/926279#926279):

> JBoss AS 7 does not work with Java 8. If you need to use Java 8
>   consider upgrading to WildFly (wildfly.org) which is a Java EE 7
>   implementation. WildFly is the new name for JBoss AS. **When you try to run AS7 of JDK8 it will hang during the boot**...

I can confirm that JBoss EAP 7 still hangs on startup with JDK 1.8. To proceed you have a several options, depending on the constraints of your development environment:

- Use an IDE other than NetBeans 8.2 to install JBoss EAP 7. The obvious choice is [JBoss Developer Studio](https://developers.redhat.com/products/devstudio/download/) from Red Hat. It's based on Eclipse, is free with registration and (not surprisingly) and makes installing and using JBoss easy. You still won't be able to use Java 8 though; you would have to use Java 7.
- Switch to using WildFly (or some other alternative such as Payara) as your app server in NetBeans, rather than using JBoss EAP 7. This approach allows you to use Java 8 to develop, deploy and test EE 7 applications within NetBeans.
- Download and install JBoss EAP 7 outside of NetBeans, and manually deploy your EE 7 applications to that server.